# How can I receive the correct url ? Trying to get the profile picture from the googlesignin account in firebase app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Ok look I have included the ability to sign in with your google account into my app and everything is working fine and all. The problem is when I try to retrieve the profileImage from that account I can display it into my ImageView but I am not getting the real download link to it you know?

```
account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
Picasso.get().load(account.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_profile).into(profilePictureImageView);
```

When I try to get the url from account I recieve this in my case:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhRv3JUcLKBQD3GSVZZbHHoQBxvPXafNlPICiU_=s96-c

But I need a url that ends on .jpg or .png or . anything so it can work on my app any ideas ? 
Like this random one I found:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-StnGV_eLi3s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABHU/XLH5wQ_Rm9E/photo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link you retrieve `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhRv3JUcLKBQD3GSVZZbHHoQBxvPXafNlPICiU_=s96-c` is an [URI](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed-in_user), What you want to retrieve is an URL, here is a [link](https://dev.to/flippedcoding/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url-4455) that explains the difference between the two.

To retrieve the URL use this `String url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();`